# Replace string in DOM element using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is a tag that looks like

```
<player id="applicationVideo" data-uuid="xxx"></player>
```

I want to replace with a variable that contains a string.

For example,

let's say I have a `viewModel` called application and it has an element called appKey. I want to store

```
var str = viewModel.application.appKey
```

into `data-uuid`

probably using jquery.

Please help!

Comment: `$('#applicationVideo').data('uuid', someValue)`

Comment: `$('#applicationVideo').attr('data-uuid', someValue)` if the above doesn't work

Comment: I tried both but the tag doesnt get replaced.

Comment: No tag is being replaced.  @KaushalNiraula 's suggestion worked when I tried it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
//Method 1
var $player = document.getElementById('applicationVideo'),
    str = viewModel.application.appKey;
    
$player.setAttribute('data-uuid', str);

//Method 2
$('#applicationVideo').attr('data-uuid', str);
```

```html
<player id="applicationVideo" data-uuid="xxx"></player>
```

Comment: Thank you. Your first method worked! But is there also a way to make it dynamically change whenever the appKey value changes?

Comment: You can make a function, when value changes, run the function.

Comment: Could you please help me to write it?

Comment: Another method: you can put value to an input[hidden], input change run that code.

Comment: I am not quite sure how to write it. Can you help?